# How can i use HTML tags in ZUL files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, zk, zul

I'm working on a zk project and i want to have some HTML tags in my zul file.

For example i want to have a table with some columns and rows but in HTML format not with zul tags. i want to set id and class for some of tags but the id of a zul tag can be used in my java code and i cant's access it from a css file. The zul tags will have some random generated IDs when zk render them to html and i can't use those ID's to set a javascript function for it or set a style in my css files.

How can i do that ? Any idea ?

Comment: You mean you wanna have some html tags during the zk tags ?

Comment: Yeah thats what i mean

Comment: I got it. There's an easy solution for that. I'll put it here as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a zul file. You must have a `<zk> </zk>` tag which contains contents of you zul file.

First you must add something like this in your `<zk>` tag :

```
<zk xmlns:h="native">
....
</zk>
```

Then you can add some html tags in among your zul tags by using `h:` before them. for example this is a table with some columns and rows within a zk `<hbox></hbox>` and also you can put some zk tags in this html tags as i put a button here in a cell of table:

```
<zk xmlns:h="native">
....
    <hbox id="zk-hbox-id" visible="true">
        <h:table id="html-table-id">
            <h:tr>
                <h:td>
                    First Column
                </h:td>
                <h:td>
                    Second Column
                </h:td>
            </h:tr>
            <h:tr>
                <h:td>
                    <button id="zk-yes-id" label="Yes" sclass="zk-sclass" />
                </h:td>
                <h:td>
                    <button id="zk-no-id" label="No" sclass="zk-sclass" />
                </h:td>
            </h:tr>
        </h:table>
    </hbox>
....
</zk>
```

Now you can use for example `html-table-id` to set a javascript function or set a css for it.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer

Comment: For the record, it's not necessary to use a `zk` tag for this. Any namespace can be added for any tag, eg: `<hbox xmlns:h="native'>`

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo code to use html tags in zul page

```
<zk xmlns:x="xhtml" xmlns:zk="zk">
<x:table width="100%" height="100%">
<x:tr>
<x:td width="40%" align="left">
</x:td>
</x:tr>
</x:table>
</zk>
```

This is a simple example to use html tag in ZUl page

Comment: i was thinking about adding an id for them too. the Kozet's answer is more useful than yours for me. i'll accept his answer if there weren't any other answer and i want you to vote him up.

Comment: Its not a issue to add id in any component at any time in component based framework, And which answer is best according to you you can accept that answer. If i know something then i am going to answer any question.